# Generate in-memory path for a saved XML document and serve to AJAX to be displayed

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-ajax, xmldocument

So, I have been running into all kinds of `CORS` errors (when using HTTPS) and `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Windows/TEMP/e3ef26_75603_4.xml` when saving my file to a temp folder and then trying to serve the request via AJAX to be displayed on my browser.

Basically the scenario is that I am requesting a file from a `S3` bucket. Now there are couple of things that I tried:

By directly giving the full file path (HTTPS) with associated bucket and file name to a `AJAX` call. This is done by first generating the file path on the `Controller` method and assigning a `ViewBag` variable. Something like:

```
ViewBag.currentURL = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tempfilepath);
```

And associated AJAX:

```
    $(function executeXML() {            
        //console.log('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.currentURL)');
        $("#myeditor").execute({
            ajaxOptions: {
                pathtoxml: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.currentURL)
            },
        });
    });
```

This method works quite well when the `S3` bucket has public access and the `CORS` policies are there for the bucket.

Problem: Using this method on a `S3` bucket that has no public access and no `CORS` policies will result in the `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` from any browser.

Sigh! But not yet,

The second method that I was trying to do is to read the file on the server side and save it to a XML document. Now when I want to save this XML document, I use a temp folder to save my file. Something like this:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    string myXMLString = client.DownloadString(fullpathstory);
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.LoadXml(myXMLString); // suppose that myXmlString contains "<Names>...</Names>"

    //Now save the file to temp folder
    tempfilepath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), filename);
    xml.Save(tempfilepath);
}
```

This gives me a path like: `file:///C:/Windows/TEMP/e3ef26_75603_4.xml`

Now when I am sending this path to my `AJAX`, it gives me the error `jquery.min.js:4 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Windows/TEMP/e3ef26_75603_4.xml` which is quite obvious and expected.

Question: I am looking for a way to save my XML document in-memory and generate a path or a stream that can be read by my `AJAX` call and serve it on the browser.

Is there such a way or do I need to create a proper file sever where I store all my generated `XML` files and then read from that location. It would basically be a temp server folder but then I would need to keep monitoring the ever increasing size of it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Rather than pre generating the file, i would recommend to generate file on demand. The moment user issues an ajax request for file, file would be generated in memory, converted to byte array, returned to client (as a base64 encoded string) and download would start at client's end.

Comment: Okay, I am not downloading any content here. Actually I am reading from a S3 bucket and then saving it to a file. I am looking for a way for my AJAX request to read this file. I expect that it should be something in memory otherwise I need to create a file server path for it.

Comment: How is "I am looking for a way for my AJAX request to read this file" different than downloading contents? When you are trying to read the file contents, contents are getting transferred over the wire from server to client. Regarding " I expect that it should be something in memory", use memory stream